# How to get the values stored in a span class in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a span class like in the attached picture. I want to fetch all three values i.e. 0.413%, 0.012%, -- and --

When I traverse to this span class and get text then all three values stored in the string but i want them one by one.
 '--' can be at anywhere. How to fetch these values.

```
<span class="text-light ng-binding" ng-show="calculatorStatus == 'COMPLETED'" style="font-size: 0.85em;">
  0.413%
<br/>
  0.012%
<br/>
  --
</span>
```

Actual: 0.413% \n 0.012% \n --
Expected: 0.413%, 0.012%, --
[image: span class image link pls open it to see the span class description]

Comment: Share `HTML` as text, not as picture. Also show your code, current and desired output

Comment: @Jitendra : You can first fetch complete String value and then split it using String split("\n") function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework.  Hmmm.  OK. I keep this in my kitbag:

```
public String getTextFromElementsTextNodes(WebDriver webDriver, WebElement element) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    String text = "";
    if (webDriver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
                "var nodes = arguments[0].childNodes;" +
                "var text = '';" +
                "for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {" +
                "    if (nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {" +
                "        text += nodes[i].textContent;" +
                "    }" +
                "}" +
                "return text;"
                , element);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("driver is not an instance of JavascriptExecutor");
    }
    return text;
}
```

It returns all characters including non-ASCII line breaks.  I usually just want the text so I add this

```
getTextFromElementsTextNodes(driver, anElement).replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", " ");
```